# Send data directly between two iDevices

Tags: ios, networking

I'm currently trying to send data directly between two iDevices, as I haven't got the resources to put a server in the middle. I've read something about GameKit offering an opportunity to achieve this, but as my app isn't going to be a game, would this still be an option?

Comment: Do you want this for two devices that are near each other or do you need support for two devices that are far apart?

Comment: What type of data you want to save? Perhaps iCloud could support your needs.

Comment: Hello, thank's for your comments. I need to send data between two devices, that are far away. :) I need to send images to each other. I tried it using the gamekit, but i have to open a new game each time i want to connect two people. Maybe there's no solution without a own server?

Comment: Anybody got an idea if this is possible? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use GameKit to send any data, but make sure that the data is not too big.
you can split data and send it in multiple message using bluetooth.

you have to implement [GKPeerPickerControllerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKPeerPickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and [GKSessionDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKSessionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

good [tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/bluetooth-connectivity-with-gamekit/) for gamekit.

Comment: Mhm.. is this also possible over 3G?

Comment: No this is to use with Bluetooth, if you want it over wifi(the devices have to be connected to the same wifi) you can use Bonjour API, if you want to send data over 3G/wifi you have to use a web service (yours) or cloud like DropBox(you upload data to user1 cloud-->send data url to user2) or use the bump API (very light and powerful api).

Answer (score 0):

Try Multipeer connectivity framework which was introduced with iOS 7.it works on Wifi as well as Bluetooth

Check this links how to workout on it.

http://www.appcoda.com/intro-multipeer-connectivity-framework-ios-programming/